# Could not determine access type for property ... the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "App\Entity\Role" given

Tags: php, html, mysql, symfony

the error :

> Could not determine access type for property "userRoles" in class "App\Entity\User": The property "userRoles" in class "App\Entity\User" can be defined with the methods "addUserRole()", "removeUserRole()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "App\Entity\Role" given...

the code :

```
   class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       $builder
           ->add('firstname',TextType::class,[
               'label'=>'Prénom',
               'attr'=>['placeholder'=>'Votre prénom ...']
           ])
           ->add('lastname',TextType::class,[
               'label'=>'Nom',
               'attr'=>['placeholder'=>'Votre nom ...']
           ])
           ->add('email',EmailType::class,[
               'label'=>'Email',
               'attr'=>['placeholder'=>'Votre email ...']
           ])
           ->add('hash',PasswordType::class,[
               'label'=>'Mot de passe',
               'attr'=>['placeholder'=>'Votre mot de passe']
           ])
           ->add('passwordConfirm',PasswordType::class,[
               'label'=>'Confirmation de mot de passe',
               'attr'=>['placeholder'=>'Veuillez confirmez votre mot de passe']
           ])
           ->add('userRoles',EntityType::class,[
               'class'=>Role::class,
               'choice_label'=>'title',
               ])
       ;
   }
```

```
public function addUserRole(Role $userRole): self
    {
        if (!$this->userRoles->contains($userRole)) {
            $this->userRoles[] = $userRole;
            $userRole->addUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

````
 /**
     * Permet de s'inscrire
     *@Route("/register",name="compte_register")
     * 
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request,UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $user=new User();
        $form=$this->createForm(RegistrationType::class,$user);
        $manager=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $hash=$encoder->encodePassword($user,$user->getHash());
            $user->setHash($hash);
            $manager->persist($user);
            $manager->flush();
            $this->addFlash("success","Inscription effectée. Vous pouvez vous connectez!");
            return $this->redirectToRoute("compte_login");
        }
        return $this->render('compte/registration.html.twig',[
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ]);
    }

```
````

Comment: Might this solution help? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41780724/1298144

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony 4 multiple entities in single form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211518/symfony-4-multiple-entities-in-single-form)

Comment: `userRoles` is a collection rather than a single property. I'm fairly sure adding `'multiple' => true,` to the definition of `userRoles` will handle the `addX` side of things.

Comment: when i used 'multiple' => true, the error was gone but i don't want the possibility to choose more than one role.is it possible please ?

Comment: What if you set userRoles to unmapped and add it manually before flushing?